# variable out of scope when using include_once

Tags: php, scope

I wrote an autoloader class.

But the `include_once` function does not include the file I need.

Cls.php(path:cls/)

```
<?php 
    class fileup{
     function dup($a){
      $x=strip_tags($a);

       $d=__DIR__."/".$x.".cls.php";
      echo $d; ///storage/emulated/legacy/htdocs/yeni/sinif/ayar.sinif.php
        if(file_exists($d)){
          include_once $d;
        }else{
       die($a." Class not found :(");
       }
     }
    }
 $dup=new fileup();
 spl_autoload_register(array($dup,"dup"));
?>
```

Theme.cls.php Theme class (path:cls/)

```
<?php 
   include_once("cls.php");
   $dup->dup("conf"); 
?>
```

Conf.cls.php Site config class (path:cls/)

```
<?php include_once("cls.php"); $dup->dup("db"); ?>
```

index.php  (path:/)

```
<?php 
  include_once("theme.cls.php");
?>
```

Error details:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error:
Call to a member function dup() on null in /storage/emulated/legacy/htdocs/yeni/sinif/conf.cls.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 /storage/emulated/legacy/htdocs/yeni/sinif/cls.php(12):
**include_once() #1** 
/storage/emulated/legacy/htdocs/yeni/sinif/theme.cls.php(3):
dup->dup('conf') #2
/storage/emulated/legacy/htdocs/yeni/index.php(2): 
include_once('/storage/emulat...') #3
{main} thrown in /storage/emulated/legacy/htdocs/yeni/sinif/conf.cls.php on line 3
```

Comment: you are not using autoloading as it should be used. Doesn't make any sense to call your autoloader function directly. There are more problems with your code, but you should spend a bit more time studying the basics before getting into this.

Comment: I understand but I Learning php oop I don't understand error  how can i solve it. where you see the wrong code

Comment: All around. Won't rewrite your code for you. You miss a basic understanding  of the subject matter to be able to ask a quality question about this. Basically, your use of autoloaders is wrong, and your autoloader is badly written (it should not `die` on not found, just return so other autoloaders may work as well).

Comment: your error output stems of your use of `include_once`, of `$dup` being out of scope by the time you reach $conf.cls.php; but most importantly, of your whole "architecture" being messed up. Look up more examples of how to work with autoloaders, because your example misses the point.

Comment: Yivi can ı write an simple example autload class code. Turkish php example/source  very little.

Comment: I understand which method(include_once()) should I use?

Comment: I could, but I wont because that's not a quality question for SO. And your actual error happens because are misunderstanding other topics (scoping, the difference between include and include_once; which are kinda basic) beyond autoloading. Look up on the web, there are tons of examples. And lucky for your, php's [documentation is available in Turkish](http://php.net/manual/tr/)!

Comment: 3month search solution. I hope my solution. Thank you have a nice day

Comment: The important bit is that despite your autoloader being a mess, your actual error is not autoloader related, but scope related. Try to reproduce your error without actually using an autoloader, which you obviously don't understand enough to try to implement; and is irrelevant to your present error output.